# Какой паттерн подходит в моей ситуации

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

В зависимости от поступающих данных класс должен предоставлять какой-то объект, который сконфигурирован в зависимости от поступивших данных. Существует ли какой нибудь подходящий паттерн или придется делать всё через switch-case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что вам подойдет паттерн строитель.

"Отделяет конструирование сложного объекта от его представления, так что в результате одного и того же процесса конструирования могут получаться разные представления."

Можно почитать тут: [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))